# How to check if a string contains a char?

Tags: c++, stdstring

I have a text file that I want to read. I want to know if one of the lines contains `[` so I tried :

```
if(array[i] == "[")
```

But this isn't working.

How can I check if a string contains a certain character?

Comment: @jamek [Which is why you provided a link to some good documentation, yes?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: `'['` would be a char literal, `"["` is a c string.

Comment: What is `array`?

Comment: `char *`, `char []`, `std::string`, `vector<char>`, any of these containers fit into the category of this question I think. @Jabberwocky

Comment: Hi @Meraj. Those tags were fine as they were. Adding `string` and `char` is not useful. Nobody searches for `char`. Thanks.

Comment: Irony is that both of the tags have more watchers and more questions than that of `stdstring`.

Answer (score 127):

Look at the documentation [`string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

```
std::string s = "hell[o";
if (s.find('[') != std::string::npos)
    ; // found
else
    ; // not found
```

Comment: What is npos? Is that the position of the string that you are trying to match the character with?

Comment: @AdanVivero, if you read the **Return value** part of the documentation, `npos` is the value returned if no such substring is found.

Answer (score 35):

Starting from C++23 you can use [std::string::contains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/contains)

```
#include <string>

const auto test = std::string("test");

if (test.contains('s'))
{
    // found!
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `std::string_view` also has a `contains` member function. This lets you write code like `std::string_view("aeiou").contains(c)` with little cost.

Answer (score 9):

I did it in this way.

```cpp
string s = "More+";

if(s.find('+')<s.length()){ //to find +
    //found
} else {
    //not found
}
```

It works even if you want to find more than one character but they should be lined up together. Be sure to replace `''` with `""`:

```cpp
string s = "More++";

if(s.find("++")<s.length()){ //to find ++
    //found
} else {
    //not found
}
```

Comment: @THUNDER07 Docs will help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Answer (score 2):

In strings, we can use `find()` to get the first occurrence (position) of the given "string"

```
string s = "dumm[y[";
int found = s.find('[');

cout<<"$ is present at position "<<firstOccurrence;   //$ is present at position 4

if (found < str.length()) {
    // char found
}
else{
    // char not found
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile! Even if you'd replace `firstOccurrence` by `found` and `str` by `s`, `find()` would return _4_, not 3. Please at least run your code and make sure it is correct before posting an answer on here, thank you!

Comment: @SebastianWilke thanks for your update. Edited the mistake I did. ill check my code before posting and won't repeat it again.!

Answer (score -1):

Use find() method, but remember find() gives the position!

```
string str;
char letter, entered_char;

cout<<"Enter  a string: ";
cin>>str;

cout<<"Enter character to be found: ";
cin>>entered_char;

//remember: find() gives the position of char
letter = str.find(entered_char);
//'letter' variable contains the position of entered_char

//if entered character is not equal to str[position found] 
if(entered_char != str[letter]){
    cout<<"Not found!";
} else {
    cout<<"Found";
}
```

Comment: Why use `char` as type of letter index? Usually `size_t` is used for sizes and indexes. In particular, here that would avoid narrowing conversion to `char` which would result in wrong value if returned index is not representable in `char` range.

Comment: And even if you used `size_t`, if the character is not found, your code would invoke undefined behaviour since `string::find` returns `string::npos` and you use it to index the string in the `if` statement using `string::operator[]`, which is defined behaviour only if its index is between 0 and string length (see [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) for details). You should instead just check whether the index is `npos` as in the accepted answer.